# How to remotely administer SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

I have administrative RDP access to a server (call it ServerA) that has access to a SQL Server 2005 service (on ServerB). I do not have RDP access to ServerB, but would like to be able to use SQL Management Studio to browse the SQL Server database.

Difficulty: ServerA does not have Internet access. To get a file from the Internet onto ServerA, I must first download it to my computer and then copy it to ServerA via RDP.

*Is there any easy way to get Management Studio onto ServerA?*

I'm hoping there is a reasonably small (50MB or so) download that contains just the administrative tools for some version of SQL Server than can administer SQL 2005, but I haven't found any.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5d76230d-580d-4874-8c7d-93491a29db15, note that there are prerequisites listed at the bottom of the page also.

Comment: Ed: That link is for managing SQL Server 2005 Express. Does anybody know what it will do with a non-Express edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download SQL Management Studio Express as suggested in the comment, I use it regularly for managing Standard/Enterprise editions of SQL Server from my workstation:

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

The second link is for the 2008 R2 edition, it's bigger (about 160MB) and requires .NET 3.5 but has several improvements like code completion for the queries.

Comment: Your first link goes to SQL Server Express, not Management Studio. I accidentally downloaded the Server and sent it over RDP before I realized it was the wrong one!

Comment: Well, the first link if for SQL Server Express but below is the link for the standalone installer of Management Studio.

Comment: I see, it's just that Ed Fries's link was more direct: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5d76230d-580d-4874-8c7d-93491a29db15

Answer (score 0):

If ServerA doesn't have internet access then there are few options available.

1) Ask for server A to be allowed internet access or browser access (at least to the Microsft website).

2) Ask for someone to insert the Sqlserver installation CD into the drive (if available) and install from there.

3) Get someone else who is located where serverA is and has access to it to install it for you.

Other than that, you're stuck with using RDP to get the installer files onto the server.